# How to project WGS84 to Kertau RSO in ArcGIS Android

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-android

How do I make a conversion from WGS84 (longitude, latitude) to Kertau RSO using ArcGIS Android?

I looking into this for my project. Am I looking at the correct direction?
I have following points in WGS84 
103.78627623849339, 1.4367857974669223
and my output points in Kertau RSO
373636336, 5170376

GeometryEngine.project(point p, spatialReference sr1, spatialReference sr2)

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GeometryEngine.project()` method is the right method, you just need to ensure your output spatial reference is correct.

```
SpatialReference srFrom = SpatialReference.create(3857) // WGS84
SpatialReference srTo = SpatialReference.create(3168) // Kertau_RSO_RSO_Malaya
// convert point
Point convertedPoint = GeometryEngine.project(point, srFrom, srTo);
```

A list of all supported projected coordinate systems can be found [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/projected-coordinate-systems.htm).